# Multiset<String> is shown empty on Android

Tags: android, string, guava, multiset

On my Android app I'm using `Multiset`:

```
Multiset<String> multiset = HashMultiset.create();
```

I want to convert it to a String using `toString()` method. The problem is that when it's a single item from every String then it looks OK, but when there are multiple strings with the same text, it is shown as `[]` instead of `[A x 2, B, C x 3]` for example.

How can I fix this so it will be shown as above instead of `[]`?

Comment: IIUYC you're claiming that `HashMultiset#toString` with strings is broken. I find this extremely improbable as it's been testet and used a lot. I'd bet that there's an error elsewhere, try to reproduce it in a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and post it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to convert `Multiset` to `Set` by calling `Multiset#elementSet` method:

```
Set<String> set = multiset.elementSet();
```

Then just call `toString` on this method to get the desired result.

Comment: But I need to get also occurrences of multiple strings as written in my question

Comment: Can you write what Guava version you use and add some code, that demonstrates this problem?